# List of Socket.io Events

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io

Does anyone know what **events** are built-in in **Socket.io**?
For example: `connection`, `disconnect`, `join` etc.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Here is all I found in the official docs:

### Client-side events for `socket.io` object:

- `connect`. Fired upon a successful connection.
- `connect_error`. Fired upon a connection error.
  Parameters:

  - `Object` error object
- `connect_timeout`. Fired upon a connection timeout.
- `reconnect`. Fired upon a successful reconnection.
  Parameters:

  - `Number` reconnection attempt number
- `reconnect_attempt`. Fired upon an attempt to reconnect.
- `reconnecting`. Fired upon an attempt to reconnect.
  Parameters:

  - `Number` reconnection attempt number
- `reconnect_error`. Fired upon a reconnection attempt error.
  Parameters:

  - `Object` error object
- `reconnect_failed`. Fired when couldn’t reconnect within `reconnectionAttempts`

### Client-side events for `socket` object:

- `connect`. Fired upon connecting.
- `error`. Fired upon a connection error
  Parameters:

  - `Object` error data
- `disconnect`. Fired upon a disconnection.
- `reconnect`. Fired upon a successful reconnection.
  Parameters:

  - `Number` reconnection attempt number
- `reconnect_attempt`. Fired upon an attempt to reconnect.
- `reconnecting`. Fired upon an attempt to reconnect.
  Parameters:

  - `Number` reconnection attempt number
- `reconnect_error`. Fired upon a reconnection attempt error.
  Parameters:

  - `Object` error object
- `reconnect_failed`. Fired when couldn’t reconnect within `reconnectionAttempts`

### Server-side events:

- `connection` / `connect`. Fired upon a connection.
  Parameters:

  - `Socket` the incoming socket.

#### Edit:

For the current version (`1.3.4`) the `reconnect_attempt` and `reconnecting`
 client-side events are synonyms.

Comment: Hmm, that can't be it, as it doesn't even list "disconnect". It seems the documentation is very incomplete. Does anybody have a proper list?

Comment: @Killroy I added client `socket` events to my answer. However I can't find server `socket` events in the docs and other places, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, I think the same socket set up is used client and server. So "client-side" is misleading, as it seems the same socket events are fired on the server end as well. I'm still hoping to get a definitive answer, perhaps from the source? Unfortunately sting-based events are tricky to track in a complex project.

Comment: @Killroy After exploring socket.io source code for awhile I came to the conclusion that server-side socket differs from the client-side one. For example, it doesn't have `reconnect`, `reconnect_attempt`, `reconnecting`, `reconnect_error`, `reconnect_failed` events, because the new server-side socket is created on each reconnection. That's all I can say by this time. I'll let you know if I find out more.

Comment: Hi Curious. I awarded the bounty for the best answer. I am not 100% convinced though that it is 100% reliable, as I don't know if you verified them all in the source.

Comment: @Killroy Thank you for the bounty. As for source code, I checked it and it seems to reflect the documentation. Also see my edit. However, socket.io versions are released very often, there is a lot of contributors, and its API may be changed in the future.

Comment: There is also a server-side 'disconnect' event (verified working in 1.3.5), though I can't actually find documentation for it anywhere. The docs are so abstract from usage though (*cough* terrible *cough*) that I might just be looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: is there an event named 'rooms' in socket.io too? need help with this question [here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553889/how-does-event-emitter-pattern-work-in-node-sockets-io)

Comment: IMPORTANT! There are more events, however we can all conclude that the docs suck.. This issue (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1814) regarding a new event (that took 2 years to officially implement) - and it is nowhere to be found. However, it is there - the event `disconnecting` can be useful.

Comment: Why didn't they just add a class containing all the constants? :facepalm: It would have been much easier

Comment: Hi! nowadays the correct link to the docs must be, for client side
https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#manager-options
and for server side 
https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/