# how does event emitter pattern work in Node , sockets.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, server

I am trying to get my hands on node ,reading through the book **node.js in action** ,I am came across this bit of code which is to be written on server side.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
socket.on('rooms', function() {
socket.emit('rooms', io.sockets.manager.rooms);
});
```

I am not sure how this works. As far as I understood the method `socket.on()` registers/adds an event listener to listen to events of type **rooms** and then callbacks a function which emits a **rooms** event..?? is that how it works? its not making sense... when does the socket object emits rooms event?

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom event, triggered by the other side. In this server side example, server waits for the client sends `rooms` event, and in the callback it responds with `rooms` event as well. Client in turn can also listen for `rooms` event.

You could name these events as you want. It is not necessary that both these events are named `rooms`.