# How to know that Android app reconnected to Socket.io?

Tags: android, socket.io

I have an android application that connects to a socket and emits `connectionData` event on the `onCreate` method.

```
// connect to socket
private Socket socket;
{
    try {
        socket = IO.socket(AppConfig.URL_SOCKET_IO);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // emit connect and connection data socket
    socket.connect();
    socket.emit("connectionData", currPlayer.getPlayerID());
}
```

On the server side, there is `activeSockets` HashMap which stores `<connectionData, socket>` data. When the internet connection is lost in the app, the server catches `disconnect` event and removes the socket from the HashMap. And when the app reconnects to the internet, it connects to the socket as well, but the app doesn't emit `connectionData` anymore as it only happens once the activity is created.

How can I detect that the app reconnected to the socket on the client-side so that I can emit `connectionData` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event listener:

```
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        socket.emit("connectionData", currPlayer.getPlayerID());
    }
});
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224287/list-of-socket-io-events) for a list of other events.