# SocketIO Server reserved events

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I wanst able to find in the official documentation what are the reserved events like `"connection"` but I see it in the examples:

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {.....}
```

I looked [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/).

*** Edit ***

Please note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224287/list-of-socket-io-events) answer gives only client side events. I am asking for server side events.

Comment: I think you are mistaking the server's events with the socket's events

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Socket.io Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224287/list-of-socket-io-events)

Comment: Afaik, `connection` is the only Server event. Everything else is a Socket event, even `disconnect`.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it under *namespace* [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-connect). I admit that the docs don't clearly state that the server is a namespace itself.

Comment: I'm surprised that none of the two people that seem to know it better left an answer or flagged as duplicate?!

Comment: @Joans W

I think that you answer is possibly the right one. I will wait a bit more to see if someone knows other events and accept it