# socket.emit() does not work when used immediately after creating the socket object but works when i call it on click events?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an issue where when i call socket.emit() on the socket object after i instantiate the socket object it does not do anything. 
Like calling the socket emit function from the constructor when React app loads. 
But when i attach the same emit to a click event like clicking a button then it works correctly. Is this because of some some asynchronous process inside the socketio module?

for eg:

```
socket = io(<someurl>);
socket.emit('something') // this does not work
```

but calling the same thing inside a click event fires the emit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The socket is not connected yet, even if just for a few ms. Try sending that initial emit when connected:

```
const socket = io(); // with your parameters

socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('something');
});
```

Here's a [list of events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224287/list-of-socket-io-events).